# React: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux

In my react/redux app whenever i pass the form data to `POST` api i get an error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined/

The data is still being submitted to the Django back-end since when i check data in my back-end, I can confirm the data i did input in the form was submitted and saved. However it's the front-end that i think has the error.
What i'm i missing?

**Form** component

```
class FormInvoice extends Component {
  state = {
    invoiceOwner: "",
    product: "",
    quantity: "",
    mode: "",
    status: "",
    payment_made: "",
  };

  static propTypes = {
    addInvoiceData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  onChange = (e) =>
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      invoiceOwner,
      product,
      quantity,
      mode,
      status,
      payment_made,
    } = this.state;
    const invoice = {
      invoiceOwner,
      product,
      quantity,
      mode,
      status,
      payment_made,
    };
    this.props.addInvoiceData(invoice); <=== Action for passing data to POST api
  };
  render() {
    const {
      invoiceOwner,
      product,
      quantity,
      mode,
      status,
      payment_made,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App container">
        <Modal isOpen={this.props.newInvoiceModal} scrollable={true}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.props.toggleModal}>Add Invoice</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="title">Name</Label>
              <Input
                name="invoiceOwner"
                value={invoiceOwner}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="title">Product</Label>
              <Input name="product" value={product} onChange={this.onChange} />
            </FormGroup>

            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="title">Quantity</Label>
              <Input
                name="quantity"
                value={quantity}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="title">Mode</Label>
              <Input name="mode" value={mode} onChange={this.onChange} />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="title">Status</Label>
              <Input name="status" value={status} onChange={this.onChange} />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="title">Paid</Label>
              <Input
                name="payment_made"
                value={payment_made}
                onChange={this.onChange}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <button onClick={this.onSubmit} className="btn btn-primary">
              Submit
            </button>{" "}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.props.toggleModal}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { addInvoiceData })(FormInvoice);
```

**Redux** part

```
// API
const api = Axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api",
  timeout: 30000,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json",
  },
});

api.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("access")) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `JWT ${localStorage.getItem("access")}`;
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);
export default api;

// ADD INVOICE DATA
import API from "../api"

export const addInvoiceData = (invoice) => async (dispatch) => {
  await API.post("/clients/invoice/", invoice)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(createMessage({ addInvoiceData: "Invoice detail added" }));
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_INVOICE_DATA,
        payload: res.data,
      });
      dispatch({
        type: TOGGLE_MODAL,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};

//Reducer
const initialState = {
  invoiceData: [],
  newInvoiceModal: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_INVOICE_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        invoiceData: action.payload,
      };

    case ADD_INVOICE_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        invoiceData: action.payload,
      };
  }
}
```

Comment: Does API.post return anything? It would return a promise or the `API.post("/clients/invoice/", invoice).then` would cause an error but does the promise resolve to anything?

Comment: API is not the same as api, JavaScript is case sensitive. Did you export api and import it as API? What is the API.post function?

Comment: Then I guess the request fails and `err.response.data` causes the error, can you see the request in the network tab and see if it fails with data?

Comment: **ADD_INVOICE_DATA** gets dispatched and the state is updated. So ``err.response.data`` is not triggered.

Comment: The only 2 places where the error `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined/` can occur in the code posted is in `payload: res.data,` or `err.response.data` maybe you can post the code where the error occurs?

Comment: The error occurs immediately after i submit input in the above **Form**  component. The error is displayed on the screen. Not the console. Above is my entire code.

Comment: @ShadowWalker i feel like your problem is on `dispatch(createMessage({ addInvoiceData: "Invoice detail added" }));`, since it doesn't looks like a true format of dispatching an action (unless `createMessage` returns an action). put it on a try catch block to see the actual error (as you can see on my answer.).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is on here:

```
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch(createMessage({ addInvoiceData: "Invoice detail added" }));
      ...
    })
    .catch((err) =>
      // not every err looks like : err.response.data
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
```

If any exception accours in the first block, the catch tries to handle it and it calls `err.response.data` . and since `err.response` is `undefined`, you get `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` error.

So add a `try catch` statement in your first block to catch the exceptions on first block currectly:

```
.then((res) => {
  try{
    dispatch(createMessage({ addInvoiceData: "Invoice detail added" }));
    ...
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(res, e)
  }
}).catch((err) =>
  dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
);
```